# Complexity of a sum with a product

Tags: np-hardness, reductions

Is the following  problem NP-complete:

**Input:** A set of tuples $T = \left\{ t_i=(a_i,b_i) | 1\le i\le n \right\}$, an integer $k$ and numbers $C,D\in \mathbb Q_{\ge 0}$.

**Question:** Exists a subset $S\subseteq T$ with $|S|\le k$ and
$$
\sum_{t_i\in S} a_i - C\cdot \prod_{t_i \in S} b_i \ge D.
$$

There are some related threads that did not really help me:

- [Knapsack combining sum and product](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31215/knapsack-combining-sum-and-product)
- [Combining subset sum and subset product problems](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20559/combining-subset-sum-and-subset-product-problems)

As the problem seems to be quite fundamental, I am quite sure that there exists a source. But I have not so many good ideas what that could be called like. I have found somewhat similar but not close enough problems:

- The Product Knapsack: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s11590-017-1227-5.pdf
- The Penalized Knapsack: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167637705000751

However all relations to Knapsack result in the issue that in the presented problem there are no weights to the tuples/elements. And connections to subset-sum fail because I require $\ge D$.

The most desirable variant for me would be $a_i\in \mathbb Q_{\ge 0}, b_i\in \mathbb Q\cap[0,1)$, but I would also be happy with an idea for the case where  $a_i$s and $b_i$s are integers.

Comment: Let's assume $a_i\ge 0, b_i \in [0,1)$.  WLOG, we can assume $|S|=k$.  Consider these two extremes:  (1) If each $b_i$ is close to 1, then the problem might be easy: $\prod b_i \approx 1 - \sum (1-b_i)$, so the problem becomes approximately $\sum (a_i+C-Cb_i) \ge D+1$, which can be solved with a greedy algorithm. (2) If each $b_i$ is far from 1, the problem also might be easy: $\prod b_i$ is exponentially small (in $k$), so the problem is approximately $\sum a_i \ge D$, which can also be solved with a greedy algorithm.  Any ideas for how to handle intermediate cases?

Comment: The idea is actually quite interesting. Indeed when the $b_i$s are relatively close to each other (informally) then we can approximate
$$
\prod_{t_i\in S} b_i \approx b_1^{|S|}.
$$
And from that point we can go greedy about the $a_i$s. That generalizes the idea for "intermediate cases". So the the question is what about $b_i$s having quite values that are not so close to each other.